# Mongo look up : Is it more efficient to have a broad query plus iteratation to find specific items or have a detailed query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wonder if a detailed mongo query with multiple query params if more efficient than a broad query with only one param like the following:

```
db.collection.find({name:name, title: title, status: status});
```

vs

```
const results = db.collection.find({name:name});
results.map(result => {
   if (result.title === title && result.status === status) return result;
})
```

Comment: No doubt at all, the first one is more efficient! Why should you read anything from disc (or RAM) which is actually not needed in the result?